# Monthpicker in Kendo UI for MVC works but sets current month when changing focus from grid cell

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datepicker

I have set up a "monthpicker" in a cell of a Kendo grid. The picker works fine and the column shows MMMM yyyy (e.g. April 2019)

However, when I move focus from the cell it doesn't set the cell as dirty and reverts back to current month and year.

Editor template (called Month.cshtml)

```cs
@model DateTime?
@{string[] formats = { "MMMM yyyy" }; }
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
                  .Name("monthpicker")
                  .Start(CalendarView.Year)
                  .Depth(CalendarView.Year)
                  .Format("MMMM yyyy")
                  .DateInput()
                  .Culture("en-US")
                  .ParseFormats(formats)
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%", title = "monthpicker" })
)
```

Model:

```cs
        [Display(Name = "Month", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [UIHint("Month")]
        public DateTime Month { get; set; }
```

View

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GrindrodDataCapture.Models.MonthlyOceanPlan>()
              .Name("grid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Month).Format("{0:MMMM yyyy}");
                  //etc
              })
              .ToolBar(toolbar =>
              {
                  toolbar.Create();
                  toolbar.Save();
              })
              .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
              .Pageable()


              .Sortable(sortable =>
              {
                  sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn);
              })
              .Filterable()
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                  .Sort(p => { p.Add("Month").Descending(); })
                  .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
                  .Read(read => read.Action("MonthlyOceanPlans_Read", "MonthlyOceanPlanGrid"))
                  .Create(create => create.Action("MonthlyOceanPlans_Create", "MonthlyOceanPlanGrid"))
                  .Update(update => update.Action("MonthlyOceanPlans_Update", "MonthlyOceanPlanGrid"))
                  .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("MonthlyOceanPlans_Destroy", "MonthlyOceanPlanGrid"))
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a support response from Telerik which fixed it :)

"Hi Evan,

I noticed that the name of the date picker editor does not match the name of the field it edits. The editor is bound to its corresponding field of the model using the name setting. Currently the binder will try to bind the editor to the `monthpicker` field of the model. However, the actual field in the model is called `Month`.

Furthermore, when using a WidgetFor helper, you can omit the name configuration as the name is automatically set to the name of the field.

Could you pleas remove the Name configuration of the editor and let me know if the editor binds as expected?"